# Google sign-in doesn't work in Huawei's "Mate 9" but works fine in any other device

Tags: android, google-signin, google-authentication

More info about the device:

> HUAWEI MHA-L09 (Android 8.0.0, API 26)

I doubt this is a code issue at all because in my desesperation to find an answer, i installed google's sign-in sample (https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/signin) and it did not work either, whenever i try to sign in on this device the screen grays out a bit and it does nothing until you tap it again and the gray goes away, when the gray goes away in my logcat i receive:

```
W/SignInActivity: signInResult:failed code=8
```

Any idea of why this happen and if there is any way to solve this?

(All the code is in the github, but if there is any other necessary information to solve this problem tell me and i will provide it)

Comment: have you added your signing certificates to dev console ?

Comment: Yes, but even if i hadn't, why does the example does not work?
since the example afaik, is already registered properly.

Comment: because sample also requires you to configure it into dev console. See this https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start

Comment: And error code 8 means `Internal Error` which is usually thrown in case of misconfiguration on console.

Comment: Oh i see, my bad then, but the question still stands, since my other project is configured into the dev console, and it does work in other devices, and i doubt that a misconfigured project will work in some devices and in some others wont.
I will try to erase and re-configure the project in the dev console tho